# How to pass values - views to controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am working in MVC (Model View Controller). I want to pass values, view to controller.. I have code but don't know about how get value in controller..

```
   <input name="Players[0].Level" id="Players_0__Level" type="radio" checked="checked" value="@t"><label for="Players_0__Level">@t</label>
```

script

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#Players_0__Level").on("click", function () {
            location.href = '/SportsDept/Create/' + $(this).find('#Players_0__Level').val();
        });
    });
</script>
```

my question is ...
this code is possible to value pass ?
and how to get value in controller ?

Please give a solution...

Regards
-AR

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: @jomsk1e  using c#.MVC5

Answer (score 0):

You can use ViewBag to pass value to view from controller:

Consider this:

Your controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewBag.DateNow = DateTime.Now;

    return View(); 
}
```

In your view:

```
@ViewBag.DateNow
```

Comment: i want to pass view to controller

Comment: sorry I misunderstood this "my question is ... this code is possible to value pass ? and how to get value in controller ?", for further learning please go here http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials

Answer (score 0):

I see you use jQuery, so instead of

```
$(this).find('#Players_0__Level')
```

try using

```
$('#Players_0__Level')
```

Answer (score 0):

change

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#Players_0__Level").on("click", function () {
            location.href = '/SportsDept/Create/?sports=' + $('#Players_0__Level').val();
        });
    });

</script>
```